# How do I implement Campaign tracking with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I am trying to implement campaign tracking in my cordova app, but I am not having success.

I previously used danwilson plugin, which works nice, but it does not have support for campaigns, as I saw here:

https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/68

So I changed my plugin to this fork:

https://github.com/Anu2g/google-analytics-plugin

Which have campaign tracking.

I am currently testing in Android, I have added this to my manifest

```
    <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As is shown in

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

And I have the campaign function in my UniversalAnalyticsPlugin.java

```
private void trackView(String screenname, String deepLinkUrl, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (! trackerStarted ) {
        callbackContext.error("Tracker not started");
        return;
    }

    addCustomDimensionsToTracker(tracker);

    if (null != screenname && screenname.length() > 0) {
        tracker.setScreenName(screenname);
        tracker.send(new HitBuilders
                .ScreenViewBuilder()
                .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(deepLinkUrl)
                .build()
                );
        callbackContext.success("Track Screen: " + screenname);
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
    }
}
```

I try to make it work using the Google guide for testing:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

I launch

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.my.app/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source%3DtestSource%26utm_medium%3DtestMedium%26utm_term%3DtestTerm%26utm_content%3DtestContent%26utm_campaign%3DtestCampaign"
```

In my cmd, and it returns

```
    Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.my.app/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Which looks to work fine. Then I open my logcat, I open the compiled app, and it logs `Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.`

As I see in the plugin docs, I have to do this:

```
To track a Screen (PageView) w/ campaign detilas:

window.analytics.trackView('Screen Title', 'my-scheme://content/1111?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=my-campaign')
```

But I dont understand how do I receive the real URL with the params, not a hardcoded one.

Someone who successfully have implemented Campaign tracking in Cordova can enlighten me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just create a single campaign link an put that one inside your application? That one is of course than trackable in analytics.

Comment: Because I want to make different campaigns and track all of them

Comment: ? Than just create a second, third, fourth or as much campaign links as you need? What do you **exactly** want to track? The users, who visit your website from out your application, or what the users are doing inside your application like which page is shown etc.

Comment: I want to track the origin of the links to the Google Play / AppStore downloads, to track if they come from email promotions, website ads... The rest of the data, like users, navigations, etc, are being tracked with the danwilson analytics plugin without problem, the issue is only in the campaigns

Comment: Ah okay, i'll post an answer - just a sec (i hope that it'll help you) :)

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much!

Comment: Let me please now if that helped but i think, that is exactly what you've looked for :)

Comment: Hmm, seems like that function is already implemented but not documented. As you can see here https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/68 there were two merges into master which added that feature - as far as i could see this.

Comment: They are implemented not in the main branch, just in two forks. The anu2g one and one tree of the asku one. That is why I change to that forks, but I dont know how to make it work

Comment: `window.analytics.trackView('Screen Title', 'my-scheme://content/1111?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=my-campaign')` with your link maybe? Bind it into a function which gets called when a specific page is shown

Comment: This is the problem, I want more than one link, and I don't know the way to diferenciate from one to another in the javascript. `var deepUrl = ????; window.analytics.trackView('Screen Title', deepUrl)`

Comment: Yes, I use JQuery, backbone, marionette and bootstrap

Comment: What about setting up an if statement which changes the var `deepUrl` like this: `$(document).on("pageshow", function (e, data) {
  var page = data.toPage[0].id;

  if page == "pageOne"{
   deepUrl = "http://url1.tld";
  }
  if page == "pageTwo"{
   deepUrl = "http://url2.tld";
  }
 })`

Comment: This should be good if I know the origin, Imagine a situation: I send emails with link1 to google play, and I use ads with link2 to google play. How do I diferenciate them? The data.toPage[0].id when the user opens the downloaded app is going to be the same, and I want to track this.

Comment: No, you missunderstood me. The `data.toPage[0].id` is just for your application. E-Mails are not openend inside your application so that the link can be build with the URL builder from Analytics to track the Mail hits exactly. If you want to track visits from different pages from the inside of your application you use the  `data.toPage[0].id`

Comment: Emails are not opened, but the url contains a referrer, When the app is downloaded from Google Play Store, the Play Store app broadcasts an INSTALL_REFERRER intent to the app during installation. This intent contains the value of the referrer parameter of the link used to reach the app's Google Play Store page, if one was present. The problem is that the BroadcastReceiver of the plugin didnt receive that. here it is some docs [link] https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns
[/link]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, and some changes in the plugin by this author, the answer can't be more obvious:

in the last revision of the plugin: https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin the author added an undocumented functionality for campaigns, and it works without any modification. It add the tags in the manifest and it works when a campaign link is launched to Google Play.

One point: the No campaign data found is also showed, but it works, even if the response is not the one that Google says

Good luck

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to retrieve the referral information and store it in localStorage. Please let us know.

Thank you.

Comment: As I know, the plugin does it automatic, so the developer dont have direct access to that information. Anyway i am going to check it next week, so I am on holidays ;)

Comment: Thank you.. Happy Holidays.. :)

Comment: It is for Android only I guess. iOS also has campaign measument feature.

Comment: Interesting information @Del. Did you finally manage to have access to the UTM data ? For example to then include it in the trackView method ? Thanks

Comment: I have done this almost a year ago, and I am not currently in that project, so I am not sure and I can't check that data. But probably you can only access to the utm data in the adquisition view

Comment: How do I disable the CampaignTrackingReceiver?