# Google campaign for cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to track the installation source of an app developed using cordova.

Im using this plugin https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/

In the `deviceReady` callback there is this piece of code:

```
 window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-xxxxxxxx-y', 30)
                  .then(function(){
                      console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
                      //the component is ready and you can call any method here
                      GoogleAnalytics.debugMode();
                      GoogleAnalytics.setAllowIDFACollection(true);
                  })
                .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));
```

also in here is the `application` tag content in the `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService" />
```

After following the google guide and testing using this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns) I get the `Broadcast completed: result=0`, so everything is supposed to be ok.

Also in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694850/how-do-i-implement-campaign-tracking-with-cordova) its said that "the author added an undocumented functionality for campaigns, and it works without any modification. It add the tags in the manifest and it works when a campaign link is launched to Google Play." means everything is done automatically, but IT IS NOT !

Am I missing something in this process, OR is there a way the get the url in the `deviceReady` callback and just use something like `window.ga.trackView('Screen Title', 'my-scheme://content/1111?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=my-campaign')` ???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it,

The whole plugin was working fine, but to make the google campaign work I needed to install "Google Play Services SDK" on the building machine. The rest is done under the hood.